# Python redirect the path by detection of ../ from anothers path

Tags: python-3.x, path

I have a path in variable A

```
A=r'\\omega3t.cr.in.com\shop\recipe\fad\prod\CPL\Wite\Proton\Coach_Color_Dress.xml
```

I have anothers path B

```
B="..\..\Type\Car\Proton.xml"
```

By using python I would like to print entire path for path B which redrive from Path A
Expected output for C is:

```
C=r'\\omega3t.cr.in.com\shop\recipe\fad\prod\CPL\Type\Car\Proton.xml'
```

Anyone have ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the powerful [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) module:

```py
from pathlib import Path

a = A.replace('\\', '/')
b = B.replace('\\', '/')

c = Path(a) / Path(b)
print(c.resolve())
```

gives `/omega3t.cr.in.com/shop/recipe/fad/prod/CPL/Wite/Type/Car/Proton.xml`

You should check if that's really what you want. It's strange to use `..` on a file path, usually that is used on a directory path.

If you really need backslashes you can still replace them:

```py
str(c.resolve()).replace('/', '\\')
```

gives `\omega3t.cr.in.com\shop\recipe\fad\prod\CPL\Wite\Type\Car\Proton.xml`

Comment: Hi , i have issue on ../ which is meaning as up one level of directory, any way to solve this?

Comment: @VivianTio you mean on the first path? You should probably start from the directory the file is in, i.e. `c = Path(a).parent / Path(b)`